# Netbeans: How to configure a remote server's PHPUnit path?

Tags: php, zend-framework, netbeans, phpunit

I use the latest version of Netbeans on Windows, and connect to a remote Ubuntu Apache server to a `Zend Framework` project. I installed on that server `PHPUnit`, but I didn't know what is the absolute path to the `phpunit.bat` (I need th absolute path in `NetBeans  Option->Php->Unit Testing`). I installed `XAMPP` on my computer and tried to use PHPUnit within XAMPP and the project from the remote server, but I have problems with the include paths, for example I get this error:

> '`Warning: include_once(PHP\Invoker.php): failed to open stream: No
>   such file or directory in Y:\mos\public_html\library\Zend\Loader.php
>   on line 146`'.

Here is my bootstrap.php file:

```
<?php
error_reporting( E_ALL | E_STRICT );
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath('Y:/mos/public_html' . '/application'));
define('APPLICATION_ENV', 'development');
define('LIBRARY_PATH', realpath('Y:/mos/public_html' . '/library'));
define('TESTS_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] = 'http://mos.loc';
$includePaths = array(LIBRARY_PATH, get_include_path());
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, $includePaths));
require_once "Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php";
$loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$loader->setFallbackAutoloader(true);
$loader->suppressNotFoundWarnings(false);
Zend_Session::$_unitTestEnabled = true;
Zend_Session::start();
?>
```

Can I set somehow the absolute path to the PHPUnit on the remote server from Netbeans, or can I make it work using the project from the remote server, and PHPUnit from my XAMPP?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your mapped network drive isn't mapped under whatever account is running the web server.

Under your own account, check what the mapping is for your Y drive:

```
C:\>net use
```

The output should be something like this:

```
New connections will not be remembered.


Status       Local     Remote                    Network

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OK           Y:        \\server\share            Microsoft Windows Network
```

Then modify your PHP script to attempt to map the drive for your scripting purposes:

```
<?php system("net use Y: \\server\share password /user:username /persistent:no >nul 2>&1"); ?>
```